# sum for each row in javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, row

I have a question about calculating sum for each row in javascript.
If I have a dataset like this:

```
data = [
    {Name: "a", Value1: 900, Value2: 700},
    {Name: "b", Value1: 800, Value2: 300},
    {Name: "c", Value1: 200, Value2: 200}
]
```

How can I get the total for each object?

Comment: Use a `for` loop or `data.forEach()`

Comment: Calculate the total as `data[i].Value1 + data[i].Value2`. Which part of this is giving you trouble?

Comment: The semicolons must be commas inside the row-objects

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all the element's properties and add the relevant ones.

```
var prop;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].Sum = 0;
  for (prop in data[i]) {
      if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop.indexOf("Value") >= 0) {
          data[i].Sum += data[i][prop];
      }
  }
}
```